# Zsh: change line editing cursor from underscore?

Tags: command-line, cursor, edit, zsh

If I attempt to edit a previous shell command (obtained through the history keys), the cursor becomes an underscore.  If the command involves a directory or filename, it is underscored already and so the cursor simply disappears.

I'm using zprezto - how can I change the cursor character or shape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cursor, it turns out, is set by the terminal emulator and not by the shell.  So once I knew that, it was easy to make the change.

Comment: Fair enough, but I've used Guake, Tilda, Roxterm, etc. which have support for 24-bit color and lots of other fancy options but only block/beam/underline cursors in the GUI settings. Block is what I might be using if it were 'standout' instead of 'reverse' - do you know if I have any options, or if I have to build from the source, or if I'm just out of luck? I've tried writing Vim styles that work well regardless of the cursor in use, but it's harder than it sounds, mostly because 'reverse' treats 'None' (transparent) as 'black' and replaces it with xterm 15 (white in the best case scenario!)

Comment: The best I've managed to do is use 'cterm=none,reverse,standout' so that the background is the old foreground, and the foreground is black, so the block cursor only changes the background from the old foreground to white and leaves the foreground black. I can also apply a style to CursorColumn and revert it with CursorLine, or vice versa, to exclude the intersection, but styling Cursor itself doesn't do much/anything because of the term emu's override. Sorry if you're not a Vim user, but it sounds like you were getting familiar with the emu/term styling relationship.

Comment: It looks like you can change the cursor from Vim, but strangely, it affects the terminal even after exiting. This is getting weird, I'll take these questions elsewhere...

` let &t_ti.="\e[1 q"
let &t_SI.="\e[5 q"
let &t_EI.="\e[1 q"
let &t_te.="\e[0 q" `